# BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT without boost

Tags: c++, boost, replace, static-assert

Since boost is forbidden in a company I work for I need to implement its functionality in pure C++. I've looked into boost sources but they seem to be too complex to understand, at least for me. I know there is something called `static_assert()` in the C++0x standart, but I'd like not to use any C++0x features.

Comment: did you ask why you're not allowed to use boost?

Comment: Nobody took the pain to build the case so that the lawyer's team give its approval for its use?

Comment: @Gregory Pakosz, they say because it is too complex :)

Comment: and can you use a compiler of some sort? because they are complex too

Answer (score 27):

One other trick (which can be used in C) is to try to build an array with a negative size if the assert fail:

```
#define ASSERT(cond) int foo[(cond) ? 1 : -1]
```

as a bonus, you may use a typedef instead of an object, so that it is usable in more contexts and doesn't takes place when it succeed:

```
#define ASSERT(cond) typedef int foo[(cond) ? 1 : -1]
```

finally, build a name with less chance of name clash (and reusable at least in different lines):

```
#define CAT_(a, b) a ## b
#define CAT(a, b) CAT_(a, b)
#define ASSERT(cond) typedef int CAT(AsSeRt, __LINE__)[(cond) ? 1 : -1]
```

Comment: Could someone explain why two CAT macros are necessary? What problem are you trying to avoid? Thanks.

Comment: If you don't do that, arguments which are macros (like `__LINE__`) aren't expanded.  So it would generate `AsSeRt__LINE__` instead of the wanted `AsSeRt42`.  I'm pretty sure there is a question somewhere explaining this in detail.

Answer (score 21):

```
template<bool> struct StaticAssert;
template<> struct StaticAssert<true> {};

int main() {
   StaticAssert< (4>3) >(); //OK
   StaticAssert< (2+2==5) >(); //ERROR
}
```

Comment: +1 simple enough, but I like to have a message associated with the assertion

Comment: @Gregory: `StaticAssert< (2+2==5) > associatedMessage();`

Comment: there are places where you don't want / can't use variables though

Comment: @Gregory: `typedef StaticAssert< (2+2==5) > AssociatedMessage_t;`

Comment: Aren't you missing the `struct` keyword in the first two lines? And the `typedef` trick doesn't appear to work - incomplete types appear to be acceptable (in fact it seems the struct might even declare, e.g a negative-sized array but typedeffing would still compile, as it doesn't instantiate the template?)

Comment: @UncleBens yes I experienced such things when crafting my own implementation until I came up with the version I posted. The use of sizeof makes sure the assertion error is not ignored by SFINAE

Answer (score 18):

Here is my own implementation of static assertions extracted from my code base: [`Pre-C++11 Static Assertions Without Boost`](http://pempek.net/articles/2013/11/23/boost-static-assert-without-boost/).

Usage:

`STATIC_ASSERT(expression, message);`

When the static assertion test fails, a compiler error message that somehow contains the `STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILED_AT_LINE_xxx_message` is generated.

`message` has to be a valid C++ identifier, like `no_you_cant_have_a_pony` which will produce a compiler error containing:

`STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILED_AT_LINE_1337_no_you_cant_have_a_pony` :)

```
#define CONCATENATE(arg1, arg2)   CONCATENATE1(arg1, arg2)
#define CONCATENATE1(arg1, arg2)  CONCATENATE2(arg1, arg2)
#define CONCATENATE2(arg1, arg2)  arg1##arg2

/**
 * Usage:
 *
 * <code>STATIC_ASSERT(expression, message)</code>
 *
 * When the static assertion test fails, a compiler error message that somehow
 * contains the "STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILED_AT_LINE_xxx_message" is generated.
 *
 * /!\ message has to be a valid C++ identifier, that is to say it must not
 * contain space characters, cannot start with a digit, etc.
 *
 * STATIC_ASSERT(true, this_message_will_never_be_displayed);
 */

#define STATIC_ASSERT(expression, message)\
  struct CONCATENATE(__static_assertion_at_line_, __LINE__)\
  {\
    implementation::StaticAssertion<static_cast<bool>((expression))> CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILED_AT_LINE_, __LINE__), _), message);\
  };\
  typedef implementation::StaticAssertionTest<sizeof(CONCATENATE(__static_assertion_at_line_, __LINE__))> CONCATENATE(__static_assertion_test_at_line_, __LINE__)

  // note that we wrap the non existing type inside a struct to avoid warning
  // messages about unused variables when static assertions are used at function
  // scope
  // the use of sizeof makes sure the assertion error is not ignored by SFINAE

namespace implementation {

  template <bool>
  struct StaticAssertion;

  template <>
  struct StaticAssertion<true>
  {
  }; // StaticAssertion<true>

  template<int i>
  struct StaticAssertionTest
  {
  }; // StaticAssertionTest<int>

} // namespace implementation


STATIC_ASSERT(true, ok);
STATIC_ASSERT(false, ko);

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very nice! This is a complete solution (and a good alternative to boost's implementation if you want to avoid boost itself) +1

Comment: If you have `-Wunused-local-typedef` and warnings as errors, this will fail to build with an error about unused typedef. That can be circumvented by adding `__attribute__ ((unused))` to the typedef in the `STATIC_ASSERT` macro (at least for gcc and clang).

Answer (score 4):

You could simply copy the macro from the [Boost source file](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/boost/static_assert.hpp) to your own code. If you don't need to support all the compilers Boost supports you can just pick the right definition for your compiler and omit the rest of the `#ifdef`s in that file.

Comment: Is that legal with Boost's license?

Answer (score 4):

I believe this should work:

```
template<bool> struct CompileTimeAssert;   
template<> struct CompileTimeAssert<true>{};
#define STATIC_ASSERT(e) (CompileTimeAssert <(e) != 0>())
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using the following header file, with code ripped from someone else...

```
#ifndef STATIC_ASSERT__H
#define STATIC_ASSERT__H

/* ripped from http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/gcc/static_assert.html */

#define ASSERT_CONCAT_(a, b) a##b
#define ASSERT_CONCAT(a, b) ASSERT_CONCAT_(a, b)
/* These can't be used after statements in c89. */
#ifdef __COUNTER__
  /* microsoft */
  #define STATIC_ASSERT(e) enum { ASSERT_CONCAT(static_assert_, __COUNTER__) = 1/(!!(e)) }
#else
  /* This can't be used twice on the same line so ensure if using in headers
   * that the headers are not included twice (by wrapping in #ifndef...#endif)
   * Note it doesn't cause an issue when used on same line of separate modules
   * compiled with gcc -combine -fwhole-program.  */
  #define STATIC_ASSERT(e) enum { ASSERT_CONCAT(assert_line_, __LINE__) = 1/(!!(e)) }
#endif

/* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679289(VS.85).aspx */
#ifndef C_ASSERT
#define C_ASSERT(e) STATIC_ASSERT(e)
#endif

#endif
```