# Test if template argument defines a specific type name

Tags: c++, c++11

Assume I have a template class like this:

```
template<typename T>
class Foo {};
```

And a class like:

```
class PossibleArg
{ typedef int required_type; }
```

Is it possible to write a static_assert in class Foo which checks if T::required_type is defined?

Comment: I'm search for a solution which doesn't require third-party libs like boost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something looks like:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
  static_assert(sizeof(T::required_type) > 0, "Never shows up");
};
```

**EDIT:** Other way: SFINAE

```
template <typename T>
struct has_required_type
{
  typedef char yes[1];
  typedef char no[2];

  template <typename C>
  static yes& test(typename C::required_type*);

  template <typename>
  static no& test(...);

  static const bool value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};

template <typename T>
class Foo {
  static_assert(has_required_type<T>::value, "Hasn't required type");
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [BOOST_MPL_HAS_XXX_TRAIT_DEF](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/has-xxx-trait-def.html), in Boost.MPL:

```
BOOST_MPL_HAS_XXX_TRAIT_DEF( required_type )

BOOST_MPL_ASSERT(( has_required_type< PossibleArg > ));
```

BOOST_MPL_HAS_XXX_TRAIT_DEF is a macro, taking a name `xxx` as parameter, which generates a metafunction `has_xxx< T >` that evaluates to true if T define a nested type named `xxx`.

(Note that an MPL metafunction is a compile-time function whose result can be accessed using `::type`. The result in this case is a compile-time boolean constant(i.e. a [bool_](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/bool.html).)

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to get a compiler error if T doesn't have a required_type you could just typedef it in Foo. Or am I missing something?

```
template<typename T>
class Foo {
  typedef typename T::required_type T_required_type;
};
```

Comment: Yes, thats how I solve the problem for now. But since C++0x defines static_assert, using it seems a nicer soltion.

Answer (score 0):

If you're actually looking for static_assert, there's something similar over here - [Static assert without boost or C++0x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980012/boost-static-assert-without-boost)